# Using Video with jQuery Cycle

Tags: jquery, video, cycle

It seems like many people have some issues once they start adding video into their jQuery Cycle slideshow, but the specific issue I am having I do not think has come up yet.

The problem is that whenever I insert a video in the slideshow, it displays fine the first time you view the slide, but if you look at the slide again (before refreshing) it is completely black.

Here is an [example of the slideshow](http://andrewpautler.com/clients/test/) and the video is on the last slide (slide 5).

Any thoughts on why this might be happening and how to correct it? And/or does anyone have some good examples of sites that use jQuery cycle and videos.

I'd love to take a look at their code to see if they are doing something that I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTube Videos take a second or two to initiate. When the css changes from `display:none` to `display:block` or similar. A fix for this would be to make a modification to the plugin or your own plugin which makes use of `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:visible` instead.

I have encountered your problem before when making a YouTube cycle, using the cycle plugin.
I decided it didn't matter so much so I left it as it was.

Example Here:
http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/HMKTS/

Comment: That's what I thought, but this is not 1-2 seconds, this is 1-2 minutes and it is still black. This happens on your version too. When you view your example, how long before the video appears? Maybe I have a localized issue?

Comment: On my work pc, and home pc , its 2 seconds max, average about 0.5 seconds. Windows 7 + FF4, IE9